# Is there a way to "expect" and "send" after "interact" command

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, expect

So I need an output of the remote process on my stdout, but I need also to be able to "listen" to it, and send the command after matching my keyword.

I need something like this (I know this code is not correct, it's only purpose is illustration of what I need)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
log_user 0
spawn ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no [lindex $argv 0] -n [lindex $argv 1]
expect "Password:" {send "mypassword\r"}
interact
expect "mykeyword" {send "\003\177\015"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I remember right, you do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
log_user 0
spawn ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no [lindex $argv 0] -n [lindex $argv 1]
expect "Password:" {send "mypassword\r"}
interact {
     "mykeyword" {
         send "\003\177\015"
         exp_continue
     }
}
```

You pass the things to watch out for and actions to take as arguments to `interact` (just like with `expect`) and you tell the response script to `exp_continue` at the end so that it keeps on interacting/expecting.

Comment: Surprising that this answer is accepted, as apparently the question was about expecting the *program* to send `mykeyword` and expect to send `\003\177\015` to the *program* as if it was typed by the user. This answer waits for the *user* to type `mykeyword` instead.

Comment: Adding `-o` before the pattern yields the intended behavior: `-o interact { "mykeyword" `.

Comment: The "-o" must be in the interact block, before the pattern: `interact { -o "mykeyword" { send "..." }}`