# Is it possible to continue execution even if "expect" does not match anything

Tags: linux, shell, interpreter, expect

Is there a way with expect interpreter to say something like

```
expect {
  "keyword1" {send "action1"}
  "keyword2" {send "action2"}
  unpredicted stuff {send "action3"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `exp_continue` in the pattern bodies to have expect loop after a match.  You may use a general `.*` none-of-the-above type regexp for "unexpected stuff", though instead of `.*` you should limit it to the line or word granularity the other keywords apply to.

Comment: here's an example of what you've said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737280/is-there-a-way-to-expect-and-send-after-interact-command. Accepting this answer, although there was no example...