# bash return control to user from expect

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I am writing a bash script with expect in it.

```
#!/bin/bash
IP1="a.b.c.d"
IP2="e.f.g.h"
HOST="xyz.com"
KEY="/path/to/key/file"
PORT="sshport"
/usr/bin/expect << EOD
    spawn ssh -p $PORT -i $KEY $HOST
    expect "*#"
    send "sh somescript\r"
    expect "Prompt from script:"
    send "$IP1\r"
    expect "Second Prompt from script"
    send "$IP2\r"
    interact

EOD
```

I am expecting to get the control back so that user can interact with the script after sending IP2 , but the script terminates, logs out of session from remote host. Any pointers  please ?

Thank you 
Amit

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7737280/1030675

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting "expect" commands, but just sending to "expect"'s stdin.

You can use "-c" to specify expect command like below, or "-f" to specify command file.

```
/usr/bin/expect -c "
  spawn ssh -p $PORT -i $KEY $HOST
  expect \"*#\"
  send \"sh somescript\r\"
  expect \"Prompt from script:\"
  send \"$IP1\r\"
  expect \"Second Prompt from script\"
  send \"$IP2\r\"
  interact
"
```